# Generating correct nuspec file... NullReference exception when using assembly that's referencing TFS assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, dll, tfs, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to publish a nuget package that has an assembly which references another custom assembly(which is another nuget package) that uses TFS assemblies for getting work item information from VSTS.

When I publish my package and try to use this dll, I'm getting NullReference exception whenever my code is trying to access TFS.

To be clear, I have published this Plugin nuget package which contains :

Plugin.dll assembly.

This assembly has some functions which retrieve information from TFS work items and do whatever work

And those functions are in TFSUtilities.dll assembly(this also has its own nuget package) which has functions to access TFS.

And this assembly(TFSUtilities.dll) references acutual TFS assemblies such as 
'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client'
'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy'
'Microsoft.TeamFoundationTestManagement.Common' .... etc.

So after publishing my Plugin.dll nuget package, when I try to reference this package from another solution and call functions in Plugin.dll to access TFS workitems, it just gives me System.NullReferenceException whenver it tries to access TFS.

I think i'm not generating correct nuspec file though. Below is the content of my nuspec file for plugin.dll.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Plugin</id>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <title>Plugin</title>
    <authors>Custom</authors>
    <owners>BCustom</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Contains custom assemblies</description>
    <language>en-US</language>

    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="TFSUtilities" version="1.6.72" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="..\bin\Release\Plugin.dll" target="lib\net452\Plugin.dll" />

    <file src="..\bin\Release\Plugin.dll" target="build\Plugin.dll" />
    <file src="..\bin\Release\TFSUtilities.dll" target="build\TFSUtilities.dll" />
      <file src="..\bin\Release\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll" target="build\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll" />
      <file src="..\bin\Release\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll" target="build\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll" />
      <file src="..\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.dll" target="build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.dll" />
      <file src="..\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.dll" target="build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.dll" />
      <file src="..\bin\Release\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll" target="build\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll" />
      <file src="..\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.dll" target="build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.dll" />
  </files>
</package>
```

I looked up on the internet and it looks like I may need to add more libraries like WITDataStore64.dll or something more but I'm not quite getting what it's talking about. Can anyone help me solving this issue? FYI, our work items are on VSTS Online.

Comment: What's the detail code?

Comment: Can you share the detailed exception message you get?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to these steps to do it:

1. Create a Class Library project (e.g. TFSUtilities)
2. Install [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/15.112.1) package
3. Copy your code and paste to this project
4. Build this project
5. Package this project by calling Nuget.exe pack [project file path (TFSUtilities.csproj)]

TFSUtilities.nuspec code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>TFSUtilities</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>TFSUtilities</title>
    <authors>WS</authors>
    <owners>WS</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>TFS API</description>
    <copyright>Copyright ©  2017</copyright>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient" version="15.112.1" />
      <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.3" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

6. Publish this package
7. Create a Class Library project (e.g. Plugin)
8. Install previous package (TFSUtilites)
9. Coding
10. Package this project by calling Nuget.exe pack [project file path (Plugin.csproj)]

Plugin.nuspec code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Plugin</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>Plugin</title>
    <authors>starain</authors>
    <owners>starain</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Description</description>
    <copyright>Copyright ©  2017</copyright>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.3" />
      <dependency id="TFSUtilities" version="1.0.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

11. Install Plugin package to other project and use it.

Comment: TFSUtilities project already has that ExtendedClients package intalled but still failing.

Comment: @JNA What're steps of yours? Could you share the simple projects one the OneDrive? BTW: I add nuspec code to my answer, you can check it.